# How can I know which Apex classes quote opportunity?

Tags: apex, opportunity

Is there a query or some option on setup that I can see which Apex Classes quote Opportunity?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) query in the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm) to get a full list of everything that directly references a given object. In your example:

```
SELECT MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType 
FROM MetadataComponentDependency
WHERE RefMetadataComponentId='Opportunity'
```

Note that this doesn't catch indirect references in Apex, such as:

```
Type.forName('Schema','Opportunity')

Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity').newSObject();

sObject oppReference = someOpportunityLineItem.getSObject('Opportunity');
```

And other such dynamic references.

However, this should get you a pretty comprehensive list, just make sure you do a search for the string `'Opportunity'` in your code to catch anything this API would miss.

Results will include email templates, flows, pages, Apex, triggers, and anything else that directly references the desired object. For custom objects, you would normally use the 15- or 18-character Id, which you can query from the CustomObject table (Tooling API).